# Wind shear questions

Tags: angle-of-attack, windshear

I had a discussion and I'm curious on an experienced pilots knowledge.  When taking off, let's say from telluride. You have a tailwind, but when you get off the ground you experience and windshear that turns into a headwind dramatically. What are the hurdles you'll face? At telluride it says to only land and take off on certain runways, so I know this could possibly happen. Also would the lift generated from the sudden increase in headwind cause the AOA to start increasing without you pulling back on the yoke???

Answer (score 2):

A headwind gust for a given elevator trim condition will result in an increase in airspeed, 
which will pitch the nose up.  The aircraft will also "balloon" upwards from increased lift.
Vertical rise will contribute to lower relative wind, but will also put additional downward pressure on tail, again raising the nose.  The effect will be temporary as AIRSPEED will rebalance to the air mass.

As always, the trim will only allow the AOA to increase a to a point before the tail goes from lift negative (downforce) to lift positive (upforce), preventing further increase in AOA.
An excessively forward CG with greater trim will make these effects more noticable.

The real danger under these conditions would be turbulence from the wind shear and 
mountainous terrain.  In light recreational aircraft, one may wish to be very cautious about
air travel until weather improves.  In the mountains, wind speed and direction can be extremely localized and variable, and should be carefully monitored.